# Multiple Publishing Pages Libraries

Tags: 2013, content-type, publishing-page

I am trying to create a second publishing  library in my site for holding News Articles. When I try and create a new Article in that library I get an exception error. Is this normal behaviour? I don't want to store lots of news articles in the same library as normal pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's limitation in SharePoint, There is only one page library per WebSite. But there are other workaround.

**Solution A**
Create sub-web to separate your article more.

**Solution B**

- Create a new Content Type inhering from "Page" content type.
- Add new column to store article categories into new content type.
- Add the content type to page library.
- Now you have 2 types of articles template to choose from.
- Further create new library View to separate it.

**Solution C**
Create folder in page library to separate your articles.

Answer (score 3):

You can have only one Pages library per site; this library is king-of hard-coded in the product.

But why don't you simply create folders/subfolders in the main Pages library, to sort your articles?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was my next thought if this was an ootb feature.